# -D in npm install

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

While installing react-router-dom, I came across a term -D in it,

```
npm i -D react-router-dom@latest
```

When I surfed online I came to know that it is -d: --loglevel info.

I need to know what exactly does this -d do and what happens if I remove this -D ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install):

- `-D, --save-dev`: Package will appear in your `devDependencies`.

You can remove it if you want and the package will show up in dependencies and not devDependencies

Comment: Also, i would install `react-router-dom` as regular dependency. Think devDependencies as something is needed only during development, like webpack, prettier, lint, etc